# Удалить часть строки между определенными символами, но с первым вхождением

Tags: php, строки

Нужно с помощью PHP удалить часть строки между определенными символами, но с первым вхождением.
Вот пример, есть текст вида:

```
<p>Текст разной длины</p>lorem ipsum <p>еще текст</p>... <p>еще текст N</p>
```

и т.п.

Из этой строки нужно удалить данные из первой пары `<p></p>` включая эти теги.

Я пробовал регулярку:

```
preg_replace('#<p>.*</p>#sUi', '', $model->text)
```

но это удаляет - все

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = '<p>Текст разной длины</p>lorem ipsum <p>еще текст</p>... <p>еще текст N</p> итп';

echo preg_replace('~<p>.+?</p>~', '', $str, 1);
```

В результате работы скрипта:

```
lorem ipsum <p>еще текст</p>... <p>еще текст N</p> итп
```

Comment: @user8494502 ну тогда вы можете его отметить галкой )

Comment: мне писало "вы можете принять ответ через 5 минут" :) сейчас когда можно конечно отмечу.